# How is praying understood within the "Death of God" theology?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, atheism, spirituality, bonhoeffer

Theologians like Hamilton and Altizer  defend a "secular Theology" that tries to banish the *Deus ex machina* of traditional Theism. So far so good, but how does one pray before God *etsi Deus non daretur*,  (to use Bonhoeffer's expression)?

How does one interpret things like, for instance, the Ignatian "consolation" felt sometimes in prayer without appealing to any "religious" agency?

More specifically: is it possible to elabore a spiritual theology without appealing to religious categories or traditional Theism?

Comment: Can you provide more sources that show what exactly Bonhoeffer taught and believed about this?

Comment: Good point. First of all, I'm not trying to say that that Bonhoeffer's position is the same as Altizer et al. What I'm saying is that there is a meeting point where these theologians have realizaed that the  "relogious god" is  dead.

Having said that, and while I'm not an specialist in Bonfoeffer's thought,  at  the end of his life he realized this idea of a "realigiousless christianity" as we read it in his  Letters and Papers from Prison. It seems to me that Bonhoeffer saw a  within the secular world a growing liberation from religious forms (Kuhns, In Pursuit of Dietrich Bonhoeffer, 196)

Comment: If all you're asking about is liberation from religious forms, then there's no question - freeform scripted or unscripted prayer is very common.

Comment: My question is more concerned about how do we *interpret* praying without traditional theism.

Comment: While interesting, that's not on topic here. We can only deal with the published doctrine and practices of established Christian groups here, not the philosophy of post-Christian philosophers.

Comment: Ok. Catholics can deal with my question then. Interpreting faith through theistic greek cathegories is not a dogma in the Catholic Church.

Comment: I have edited my question adressing it to Catholics only. Hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: I strongly suggest you remove Bonhoffer from the list (since his association with the movement is disputed at least) and substitute another name such as van Buren or John Robinson. Secondly, why would you want a Catholic perspective? None of these theologians are Catholics. It would be much better to ask what the movement itself thinks about this matter.

Comment: @curiousdannii By the definitions of this site the theologians mentioned are Christians. It's perfectly allowed to ask about their views.

Comment: @DJClayworth I think it's dumb that so called "Christian Atheists" are on-topic, but if they all do self identify as Christians in a spiritual sense (and not only in a cultural sense) then this may be on-topic. But do they form a unified group, or are they philosophising as individuals? It's definitely nonsensical to be asking about it from a Catholic perspective. And do any of the named people even suggest that praying is appropriate?

Comment: @curiousdannii 'Unified' would be overstating it, but they are a recognizable group.

Comment: Well I'm asking it "from a Catholic" perspective because it was suggested to me that I should be more concrete in my question. Like  DJClayworth, I do think that this thinkers are *Christians* and it is perfectly legitimate to ask about their views.

Comment: And it makes perfect sense to ask this question from a Catholic perspective since there are Catholic theologians who agree with Bonhoeffer or Altizer on a variety of topics, like the secular reading of the Scriptures, for instance. But I do honestly prefer to ask this from the very same "christian atheist" perspective.

Comment: I made an edit that I think captures what you want.

Comment: @Jasso There's a **massive** difference between reading scripture from a neutral secular perspective and actually believing that God doesn't exist. If you want to ask from the so-called "Christian Atheist" perspective that's okay, but don't mix it up with Catholicism. And you should demonstrate that those "Christian Atheists" do themselves pray.

Comment: @curiosdannii That's the whole point!.I *suppose* the actually pray, but the point here is what they do understand by  *praying*. It seems like an obvious question --"what is praying?"-- but that's the point of my question, I'm trying to understand what is meant *by praying* within the  "Christian Atehism" perspective.

Comment: @curiosdannii A secular perspective is not neutral at all. It's just a perspective, like the religious perspective, or the mythological perspective, or the philosophical theistic perspective. *In this sense*, I think Bonhoeffer and Altizer et al are playing in the same league, don't you think?

Comment: Only somewhat relevant, but you might try this essay: https://progressingspirit.com/2016/11/24/a-new-christianity-a-new-prayer-bishop-spong-style/

Comment: @Jasso Supposing doesn't make a good basis for a question. You really should find some evidence that they do pray or promote praying.